# Why is "asked" on my question say today when it was asked yesterday?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

On 4/14/11 at 10:35 PM EST I asked the question "[Outlook 2003 does not import .ics calendar while outlook 2007 does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670515/outlook-2003-does-not-import-ics-calendar-while-outlook-2007-does)" on SO yet on 4/15/11 at 8:18 AM EST the question says it was asked today.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time stamps (as with everything else on the site, for your future reference) adhere to the UTC timezone, not on the user's timezone. In this case, 22:35 EST corresponds to 02:00 UTC, which is in the same day as 12:18 UTC (or 08:18 EST).