# The question asked 2 days ago was "asked yesterday"? Let's fix the confusion!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Yesterday” time specification shown when it was actually the day before yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127668/yesterday-time-specification-shown-when-it-was-actually-the-day-before-yesterd)

I asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538743/what-to-do-if-mousemove-and-click-events-fire-simultaneously) on 26 January at 16:07:44.

Today, on 28 January at 15:06:12 GMT+2 it is marked as *"asked yesterday"*, while tooltip message still displays the "2 days back time":

[image: Odd date]

I've found almost the [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/why-is-asked-on-my-question-say-today-when-it-was-asked-yesterday) on Meta from April 2011. And I guess the *"problem"* remains because of different time zone used internally, besides my basic calculations still can't give me *"yesterday"* for the given time (and it seems I'm wrong).

Anyway, even if my maths is bad, and the question can be tagged with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), I see an *obviously confusing discrepancy of labels and tooltips*. Maybe we need to change the contents of labels to make things more clear? Since mentally for me *"yesterday"* was yesterday from the wake up till night sleep, but not 46 or 47 hours ago. Meanwhile many even might not know what `Z` in the date means.

Let it be a feature request. What I see to be less confusing:

1. before 48 hours: *"asked/answered X hours ago"*
2. after 48 hours: *"asked/answered MMM DD 'YY at HH:MM"*

In order to prove my idea, here is a [link to English online dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/day) for the word "day". We can see that there are several common meanings like: *"when you are awake"*, *"not night"*, *"time at work"*, which contradicts with the astronomical meaning of the word.

Comment: Short info: You didn't ask that question at 16:07 of your time, but at 16:07 UTC. Still confusing as it wasn't yesterday even in UTC.

Comment: Equate downvotes on this with "I've gotten used to this weirdness and am now just comfortable with it, screw clarity for everyone else."

Answer (score 8):

Posting times are displayed in the UTC timezone. At the time you took that screenshot, it was 13:06:02 UTC, and the post was made less than 45 hours before. You can see that in the time displayed in the tooltip; it's formatted as a [ISO 8601 date time string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC); the `Z` stands for the UTC timezone.

You need to wait another 4 hours before it'll show that it was asked 2 days ago.

If you look at the reputation dropdown in the top bar, you'll find it displays the current time in UTC:

[image: UTC time]

Comment: OK. Thanks for giving a reason for that, I see that I am totally confused with time zones. But the request still remains: the users shouldn't know anything about the internal time, they need a clear time display, considering their own time zone.

Comment: @VisioN: Do you see that the time display in the title tooltip has a `Z` behind it? That [`Z` means UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) time..

Comment: So, does it mean that it shouldn't be yesterday by all means, if I definitely asked the question two days ago?

Comment: @VisioN: Any age between 24 and 48 hours old is called 'yesterday'.

Comment: Not to most humans.

Comment: The problem is that the definition of "yesterday" differs from timezone to timezone. SE users live all over the world! Only after 24 hours is it *definitely* yesterday for each and every timezone on earth.

Comment: I would like my questions to be marked as being asked two days in the future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Mathematically it is true, but not mentally. For me yesterday was on 27th from my wake up till the late night, when I went to bed. And I'm sure most have the same criteria.

Comment: @VisioN: Not just mathematically. For *someone* in the world, you posted that question at 00:07. It won't be 'yesterday' for them until 24 hours later. That's the reality of running a site for a worldwide audience.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then I'd refuse of utilizing the constructions like "yesterday", "2 days ago" etc, since "day" as a word has different meanings.

Comment: @DaveNewton I would also like to reserve a table at the restaurant at the end of the universe ^_^. I heared that Jon Skeet has his personal chair there, just near Chuck Norris one (so THAT is how he manages to always reply before others)